# Reading SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), which seems to produce an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am populating a MySQL database using PHP and SQL languages. The table I am populating is called project. After I add the record to project, I would like to send out an email including the project_id and project_title. I thus need to know the project_id after I populate the project table.

The command: $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"; is returning an array. I have tried several guesses of what is in the array, without any luck.

```
public function add_project($project_title, $project_description, 
        $skill_cat_id, $name_id) {
    $dbConn = new DatabaseConn();
    $this->name_id = $name_id;
    $this->skill_cat_id = $skill_cat_id;
    if($this->check_for_duplicates() != null) {
        $message = "This Project already exist!";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO project "
                . "(project_id, project_title, project_start_date, "
                . "project_description, skill_cat_id, volunteer_id, response_id, name_id) "
                . "VALUES (DEFAULT, $project_title, DEFAULT, "
                . "$project_description, $skill_cat_id, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $name_id)";
        try {
            $dbConn->exec($sql);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            $message = $sql . "<br />" . $e->getMessage();
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }
        $dbConn2 = new DatabaseConn();
        $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
        try {
            $statement = $dbConn2->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute();
            $result = $statement->fetch();
            $statement->closeCursor();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            $message = $sql . "<br />" . $e->getMessage();
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I am expecting the project_id of the project table, yet the command is returning an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PDOStatement::fetch()` always returns an array, which is one row of the result set. The array is either an ordinal array or a hash array indexed by column name.

It doesn't matter that your query is guaranteed to have one column and one row. It's still a result set, for which `fetch()` returns an array. The array it returns will have one entry, corresponding to the single column of your query.

If you want to return just one column as a scalar, try [PDOStatement::fetchColumn()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

See the documentation for description and a code example.

Comment: Replacing fetch(); with fetchColumn() resolved the issue and I now have the ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can get last insert Id from the pdo object itself. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php